# Measuring the distance to a sound

Tags: acoustics

Do you know if there is some sort of equipment that can measure the distance to a sound? What practical application can such an equipment have? The reason I'm asking is because I just got an idea of how to make such a machine. But it's really not hard to figure out so I guess there already exists such things. I didn't find anything on google though. Thanks.

Comment: You can't measure the distance to a sound without knowing something else about it.  If you know how loud the sound was originally, then you could use the $1/r^2$ law to calculate the distance.  If you know when the sound was initiated, then you can measure distance by counting the time to reach you (i.e. the lightning trick).

Comment: Regardless, this question is too broad as it is.  Why don't you tell us you idea, and we will give you advice on how feasible it is?

Comment: Very well. First we need a device which can detect from what direction a sound is comming from. If no such device exists we may build one by setting up a lot of small microphones in a circle and see which one receives the most sound. Then lets (theoretically) draw a line in the direction of the sound. 
Then we then have another of those sound devices places a distance apart from the other. Then we draw a line from that device in the direction of the sound aswell.
The sound source is where these lines cross each other. Then the distance can be calculated.
Hope u understood. Ask if you didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this in fact, there are acoustic devices used by the military to [detect the location of sniper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomerang_(countermeasure))s. However, this is something of a special case and it relies on detecting not just one sound but a well understood acoustic signature. In the case of a bullet you have the sound of it being fired and the sound of the sonic boom as it passes. In fact crude rules of thumb have been used to get rough distances for as long as supersonic ammunition has been used.

Similarly,  because this is a particular application you can also infer a lot of extra information about the likely speed and trajectory of a bullet.

The tricky part is not so much the hardware as the processing required to process the information into something useful.

Obviously with familiar sounds human hearing is pretty good at determining distance and direction, although this can be hampered by echos and the general acoustic environment.direction can, in general be measure by the small delay in receiving the sound between two or more receivers and the distance by how loud the sound is (as long as you know how loud the sources is).

So the principal is fairly simple and essentially similar to active radar and sonar systems. The difficulty comes in the fine detail of specific applications particularity in accounting for complexities  like changes in speed of sound due to variations in air density and interaction of sound with obstacles.

Comment: You don't need to know the amplitude of the source in order to determine the distance. You can use triangulation, and the processing is trivial. I think you would need a minimum of 6 sensors, the further apart they are, and the more precicesly you can measure the timing differences, the more accurate your distance calculation will be.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of a device with multiple microphones some distance apart (enough that you can measure the delay between each one), which you could then use to triangulate the direction and distance of the sound source.

Such a system was used to track submarines during the second world war. [RAF Nimrod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Siddeley_Nimrod) planes would drop buoys into the ocean which had hydrophones, and they would transmit the sound they heard back to the plane. The staff aboard could then decide where to drop another buoy in order to get the best angle for triangulating the submarine position as it moved around trying to avoid detection. You can read about this more on the [anti-submarine warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-submarine_warfare) Wikipedia page. Since then, the US Navy deployed a more permanent system called [SOSUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOSUS).

So yes - there does already exist a device, or rather a network of devices, for finding the direction and distance of a sound source. I don't know if there is a smaller singular device for doing this same thing on land, but it's certainly viable.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know if there is some sort of equipment that can measure the distance to a sound [source]?

A familiar example of this is estimating the distance to a lightning strike. The light arrives nearly instantaneously. The sound travels at 340 m/s at sea level (at standard temperature and pressure). By measuring the time between the light and sound arriving we can estimate the distance to the source. It's roughly 3 s/km or 5 s/mile.

Without the light source the problem becomes more difficult.

- One microphone doesn't give you any location information.
- Two microphones may tell you the 'line' that the source is on but not the range. e.g. For two microphones 100 m apart a difference in time of 0.1 s (34 m) gives a location of the sound somewhere on an infinite curve that passes between them.
- A third microphone is required to triangulate the source.

The system will have to deal with background noise, echos, changes is sound *ground* velocity due to wind, etc.